# Rotate a Texture2D with the Draw method in XNA?

Tags: c#, xna

I have a problem with rotating. I know that I can rotate a Texture2D object with the draw method.

My goal is to rotate a texture by 180°. For example, if I make a picture of a human with the camera where the head is at the bottom, I want to be able to rotate it so that the head is at the top again.

Here is the code or the rotation:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(Texture, Position, null, Color.White, MathHelper.Pi, new Vector2(), 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
```

The rotation works fine, but I have another problem:
[image]

If I add the texture to position 0,0 after rotating it, it's not visible anymore.

**How do I rotate or maybe reflect the object, so that the red point will be at the top-left corner again?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433989.aspx

```
public void Draw (
     Texture2D texture,
     Vector2 position,
     Nullable<Rectangle> sourceRectangle,
     Color color,
     float rotation,
     Vector2 origin,
     Vector2 scale,
     SpriteEffects effects,
     float layerDepth)

//Using:
var origin = new Vector2()
{
    X = texture.Width / 2,
    Y = texture.Height/ 2
};


spriteBatch.Draw(texture, Vector2.Zero, null, Color.White, MathHelper.Pi, origin, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f)`
```

Comment: this is not the right solution, because then the 0/0 from the sprit is not in the top-left position.

Comment: As a side note, I recommend defining sprite positions by their centers instead of the top left anyway. It's more intuitive and saves headaches with positioning and collision.